# Position of label caption inside ProgressBar

Tags: delphi, label, progress-bar

I want to put a label inside progress bar. And this label caption is dynamic.
How can I get the label position ALWAYS on center inside the ProgressBar?

What I've tried ;

```
  Label1.Parent := progressBar1;
  Label1Top :=  progressBar1.Height div 2;
  Label1.Left :=  progressBar1.Width div 2
```

It shows ugly, and not in center like I want.

[image: Label inside progress bar]

If I set `Label1.Left := progresBar1.Width div 2 - xxx` it will be on center only for certain caption. I want to have any caption be placed on center.

**Edited**
Answer from @KenWhite is working good.
Solution from @DavidHeffernan just great.

[image: ProgressBar with Text]

Comment: @KenWhite yes Sir, I already did. That picture show of label align`taCenter `

Comment: (progressBar1.Height - Label1.Height) div 2

Comment: I would suggest that you paint the text directly rather than using a label control. Make the painting of the text part of the control's paint routine so that the control stands alone.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you Sir, that would be my next lesson ;) One example by using text painting method would be just great.

Comment: Plius one for Label1.Parent := progressBar1; - that solved my problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set the label's `AutoSize` property to `False`. Change the `Alignment` property to `taCenter` and `Layout` to `tlCenter`. Size the label to the  progressbar's `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight`, and set its `Left` to `0`.

```
Label1.Parent := progressBar1;
Label1.AutoSize := False;
Label1.Transparent := True;
Label1.Top :=  0;
Label1.Left :=  0;
Label1.Width := progressBar1.ClientWidth;
Label1.Height := progressBar1.ClientHeight;
Label1.Alignment := taCenter;
Label1.Layout := tlCenter;
```

Here's an example of the appearance:

[image: Image of standard sized progress bar] [image: Image of double height progress bar]

Comment: BINGO ! This works great like i want. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should probably also make `Label1.Transparent := True` in case  themes are not used. +1

Comment: One last thinng: I would probably use `Label1.Align := alClient;` with `Label1.Alignment := taCenter;
  Label1.Layout := tlCenter;
  Label1.Transparent := true;` so if the ProgressBar grows at runtime the label is always aligned to `alClient` and centered.

Answer (score 15):

You might decide to derive a progress bar control that paints the text itself rather than relying on a separate label. Some sample code to demonstrate:

```
type
  TProgressBarWithText = class(TProgressBar)
  private
    FProgressText: string;
  protected
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  published
    property ProgressText: string read FProgressText write FProgressText;
  end;

procedure TProgressBarWithText.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  DC: HDC;
  prevfont: HGDIOBJ;
  prevbkmode: Integer;
  R: TRect;
begin
  inherited;
  if ProgressText <> '' then
  begin
    R := ClientRect;
    DC := GetWindowDC(Handle);
    prevbkmode := SetBkMode(DC, TRANSPARENT);
    prevfont := SelectObject(DC, Font.Handle);
    DrawText(DC, PChar(ProgressText), Length(ProgressText),
      R, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER);
    SelectObject(DC, prevfont);
    SetBkMode(DC, prevbkmode);
    ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
  end;
end;
```

The advantage of this approach is that your progress bar and text display are self-contained. There's no need for two separate controls that you have to coordinate.

Comment: Thank you Sir!. Yes this is cool. But this kinda too advance for me. May I have one more example of the implementation on progressing step + text by using `TTimer` ?

Comment: Well, it's all here. You just use this control and set the `ProgressText` property. To do that at design time you'd need to add and register the control in a design time package. If you were prepared to set `ProgressText` at runtime you could use an interposer class.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan GREAT! Thank you so much. Edited first post. Thanks again.

Comment: Although, in my view, using a single control is better than a control and a label, I don't think you should accept this answer. I would prefer it if you accepted Ken's answer since it directly answers the question that you asked. I just offered an alternative way to look at the entire problem. Ken's answer is a better fit to the question you asked, in my view.

Comment: Aha, per post title, yes it is.. OK then. Have a nice day Sir.

Comment: The required units for the above code are: ComCtrls, Messages, Windows.